# Joining Table Row and table Column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a table called `Tbl` with `n` number of columns with `n` number of `rows`.

```
Create Table Tbl(Col1, Col2, Col3,...)
```

I have another table called `TblColNms` in which I am maintaining column names.

```
Create Table TblColNms(ColId, ColNms)
```

In `TblColNms`, I insert the column names of table '`Tbl`'. For example:

```
Insert into TblColNms(1, Col1)
Insert into TblColNms(2, Col2)
```

My requirement is:

To retrieve only the columns which was inserted in `TblColNms`.
For ex.:

```
Select (Select ColNms 
        from TblColNms) 
from Tbl
```

Which should return all rows from `Tbl` but with only those 2 column names.

Comment: This will be achieved using dynamic query. Are you going to store table name also in `TblColNms`? How can you handle more than one table's columns?

Comment: @SelvaTS: Could you please give me a code snippet please. Is there any other option available other than dynamic query?

Comment: I don't know there is other option than dynamic query. But I can give you some code snippet for dynamic query.

Comment: Why do you have a table to hold the names of the columns in your table??? That sounds like a horrible design. Not to mention you have sys.columns which already contains all the columns for every table.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you are storing data in form of stack. You can use PIVOT with dynamic query to achieve this.

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(Course)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Course FROM #CourseSales) AS Courses

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT Year, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #CourseSales
    PIVOT(SUM(Earning) 
          FOR Course IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Original author: http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

Comment: Interesting answer. I like the possibility but would have been good to see this answer applied to this question

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @CMD NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @TABLE_NAME = 'dbo.Table1'
SET @CMD = 'SELECT '

SELECT @CMD = @CMD + ',' + ColNms
FROM TblColNms

--eliminate leading comma
SET @CMD = REPLACE(@CMD,' ,',' ') + ' FROM ' + @TABLE_NAME

PRINT @CMD
EXEC sp_executesql @CMD
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get SQL Server to convert a series of row values to a comma delimited list by using FOR XML PATH('') as follows:

```
SELECT ',' + colName from ColumnNames for XML path('')
```

This would give something like `,first_column,another_column,last_column`

If you do this within a declaration, you can execute the resulting statement much like eval() works in javascript using sp_executesql

I used STUFF here to delete the first comma

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ' 
           + STUFF((
                SELECT ',' + colName from ColumnNames for XML path('')
             ), 1, 1, '') + ' FROM Product';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need a result of row-set by some special column names those stored in a table:

1. You need a Stored Procedure that can give your results statically, like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP1 AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @query as nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT '
    SELECT @query = @query + ColNms + ','
    FROM TblColNms

    SET @query = LEFT(@query, LEN(@query) - 1 ) + ' FROM Tbl'
    EXEC(@query)
END
GO
```

And you will have your result by executing it like this:

```
EXEC SP1
```

2. Make a table like `Temp1` and query over it like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP2 AS
BEGIN
    IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Temp1]') AND type in (N'U'))
        DROP TABLE [dbo].[Temp1]

    DECLARE @query as nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT '

    SELECT @query = @query + ColNms + ','
    FROM TblColNms

    SET @query = LEFT(@query, LEN(@query) - 1 ) + ' INTO dbo.Temp1 FROM Tbl'
    EXEC(@query)
END
```

And when you want your result use it like this:

```
EXEC SP2

SELECT * FROM Temp1
```

This way will give you more options like adding conditions and etc. to your results like:

```
SELECT Top(<n>) * 
FROM Temp1 
WHERE <condition>
```